# How to detect collision?

Tags: python, tkinter, collision-detection, collision, maze

I’m doing a maze where I need to detect a collisions of the balloon and the walls.The maze is created in tkinter. I created the walls with c.create_line. And I have no idea how to write the code for the collision since I have 70 walls.

I’ve tried giving the walls tags and if the balloon==walls it would restart but nothing happens.

Comment: if balloon hits walls then game should restart?

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag yea I want it to go to its original x,y

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@morevinyl/tkinter-collision-detection-on-canvas-made-simple-320ae6cc58e1 @alea

Comment: @D.L thanks sm i will try that too